# Display database value in textarea when user select value from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My goal is it to print the data from the database into a textarea when user selects an item from the dropdown list.

Display items from database in dropdown list:

```
    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
            $dropdownItem = $rows['dropdownItem'];
            echo "<option value='$dropdownItem'>$dropdownItem</option>";

    }
```

At least i managed to insert the text of one dropdown item into the textarea field

```
    var select = document.getElementById('select');
    var input = document.getElementById('textareID');  
    select.onchange = function(){
       input.value = select.value;
    }
```

But actually I want to display the text from another tabelle in the database at the same time, when I'm pressing an option at the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('#text_area').val( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<textarea id="text_area"></textarea>
```